# How to find the ssl / tls master key

Tags: ssl, openstack, openstack-nova

I tried posting this on ask.openstack but it has been stuck in the moderator for 5 days now.  I thought I'd try here.

I was trying to debug a Nova issue and wanted to decode the SSL / TLS packets being exchanged using Wireshark. Part of the changes I was making was setting Nova up to use SSL / TLS and I wanted to be sure that part of it I had set correctly. I eventually figure out my issues from the various log files but I'm somewhat assuming that being able to watch the network traffic may help in some very difficult cases.

The exchange uses TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 at one point. According to this [security stackexchannge](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35639/decrypting-tls-in-wireshark-when-using-dhe-rsa-ciphersuites) question, there is a "pre-master secret" or various other terms. I've wrestled with this before in a previous life doing IPSec. Usually you can set debug in the application and it will spew out the secret into the log file. I tried "debug = true" under Default in nova.conf and got lots of debug but no secret. There was two items that looked interesting that were reported as **** in the log: keystone_authtoken.memcache_secret_key and neutron.metadata_proxy_shared_secret. I wasn't sure if those were the secrets I was looking for or not. In this case, I'm looking at the nova-api traffic going to port 8774.

Also, since all of openstack is Python and uses the same "request" and "certifi" packages, it may be possible to generalize this to all of the openstack components.

nova --version report 9.1.1

Comment: It is not common for TLS applications to log the master key, even if debugging is enabled. And I don't even see that Python provides such functionality in ssl.py.  You might though take a look at [Extract pre-master keys from an OpenSSL application](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80158/extract-pre-master-keys-from-an-openssl-application).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich You have the feature in PyOpenSSL, I used it recently in fact: `client_random()` and `master_key()` can be called on a `Connection` object.

Comment: I know nothing about Nova but the two key names you quote do not look like to be related to TLS at all in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you to all.  I will look at the link Steffen pointed me to.  Perhaps others will comment as well.